# ActiveSheet.Paste gives error...but only sometimes? Alternative to it's use?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro, it filters a sheet, copies the filtered data and pastes it into another workbook.  It worked the first few times I used it, now it gives me an error:

> Run-time 1004 - We can't Paste because the Copy area and Paste area
>   aren't the same size.

Nothing changed, it just now flags the error on the "ActiveSheet.Paste" line.  Can anyone explain why it does this out of nowhere randomly?  I know tomorrow when I try again it will work fine for a few uses then do this again.  I looked online it seems to be a common issue, I haven't found a solution that has worked for me yet, does anyone have an idea?  Or is there another way to do this maybe so I can just avoid it?

The code:

```
    Sub Macro201()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$H$55").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="99"
    Range("A7:B7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("invoiceTEST.xls").Activate
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select


    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Did the filter result in only one record being selected?  And is the source file in the 2007+ format?  If so, you will be selecting more rows than can be copied to a 97-2003 format file.  Even if the source file is a 97-2003 file also, there is a chance this will happen if you try to copy 65500 (for instance) rows to a destination address of A50 (for instance).

Comment: I'm using 2013, I made sure it saved new format.  It was only copying 5 rows, at most it would ever copy maybe 10.  The unaltered report is at most 1000 lines and before I use this it is always knocked down to 50 or less rows to filter.

Comment: You say in a comment to an answer that sometimes there are no 99s in column H.  I'm not sure why it would then be copying 5 rows - I would expect it to be copying `$A$7:$B$1048576`.  To check this, place a `Debug.Print Selection.Address` immediately after your `Selection.Copy` line.  You will see that it displays `$A$7:$B$1048576` every time you select either 0 rows, or just row 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to select anything. For example, `Range("A7:B7")` is a range. `Selection` is also a range (in this context). So, you assign the range to a Selection.Range and then use the Selection.Range. Why not use the Range you defined at the outset?

Next, you do have to specify the Worksheet you are working on, especially the one in the target workbook.

Finally, you must clearly identify the last rows you use. Your formula picks the last row in the sheets you work with, not the last **used** row. So you are throwing around millions of blank cells.

Put all of the above together and you arrive a code like the following.

```
Sub CopyData()
    ' 01 May 2017

    Dim Rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = .Range("$A$6:$H$55")
        Rng.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="99"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Rng) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        .Range("A7:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    End With

    With Workbooks("invoiceTEST.xls").Sheets(1)
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the code will fail if the target workbook isn't open when you attempt to run it.

Comment: Thanks, I do keep both books open so it works fine. I'm new to this, it's only the second time I've tried to really make something like this so I was just using the recorder and altering it a little for simple tasks. I appreciate the code clean up.  Is there a way to make it do nothing if there are no "99" in column H?  Right now if there is nothing it filters the sheet to blank and copies the A6 filter header row.  I can work around that and delete the useless paste automatically if not.  Thank you again.

Comment: I have added a line of code to curtail the action if the filter returns no results. I haven't tested the code for lack of data, but if it works please don't forget to "accept" the answer so that others can reap the fruit of your testing effort. :-)

Comment: It did work, thank you very much, I really appreciate all your help.